# PHP - Switch case evaluates to true while the same statement in if doesnt

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I don't quite understands this.. Take a look at the following:

```
$value = 0;
if($value >= 90) {
    // this does not return true
}
switch($value) {        
    case $value >= 90:              
        // this however does
    break;  
}
```

Am i missing something very obvious ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$value >= 90` evaluates to `false`

As `$value` is 0, it is considered `false`. That's why your `case` works.

In a simple way it can be rewritten as:

```
switch($value) {        
    case false:              
        // this works
    break;  
}
```

Comment: The manual describes this pretty good: [*"Only when a case statement is found whose expression evaluates to a value that matches the value of the switch expression does PHP begin to execute the statements."*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). Also to note is that switch does a loosely comparison.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks!